# Set up Drupal 6 replication

Tags: drupal, replication

I am setting up Drupal with a user that has only SELECT (read) rigths as the database is a SLAVE in a replication. I don't need to use the login or any writing from this client. I want to know what tables should I remove from replication so it will show content. Right now I get a "site offline" probably because it cannot do any writes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. It seems that I had to find the answer for myself.

Remove the following tables from the replication process and allow the user to do writes on them.

```
accesslog
cache_block
cache_content
cache_filter
cache_form
cache_menu
cache_page
cache_rules
cache_update
cache_views
cache_views_data
sessions
watchdog
```

If you have other module cache table, try with those as well if is not working. In order to use the login you have to remove users from replication as they are writing the last user access directly in the user table (which I think is not a very good idea), but you will lose replication on a very important table.

So no login if you want replication. Good luck